# Norwegian Characters as '?' in ics c#

Tags: icalendar

I have been trying to send calendar event ics in a mail as attachment but the summary and description is showing norwegian character like 'ø' as '?'.

Please help me as I am new to the calendar events in ASP.Net MVC.

```
    System.Text.StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
        str.AppendLine("PRODID:-//Schedule a Meeting");
        str.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
        str.AppendLine("METHOD:PUBLISH");
        str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}",model.Startdate));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTAMP:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.UtcNow));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", model.EndDate));
        str.AppendLine("LOCATION: " + model.Location);
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("UID:{0}", Guid.NewGuid()));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("DESCRIPTION:{0}", model.desc));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("SUMMARY:{0}", model.Name));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:{0}", model.Email));
        str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VALARM");
        str.AppendLine("TRIGGER:-PT15M");
        str.AppendLine("ACTION:DISPLAY");
        str.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:Reminder");
        str.AppendLine("END:VALARM");
        str.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
        str.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str.ToString());
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

        Attachment attach = new Attachment(stream, "Invitation.ics");`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're loosing the special characters when using the ASCII Encoding. Use some other Encoding, e.g. UTF8, which is a variable multi-byte encoding that can cover all characters.

The attached link shows how to specify the used encoding in the ics file:
https://theeventscalendar.com/support/forums/topic/ical-text-encoding/

Comment: Thank you so much for such a prompt answer. Sorry for asking such a silly question though. I was stuck from a long time. Thanks again!